# Running python scripts for different input directory through bash terminal

Tags: python, linux, bash, unix

I am trying to automate my task through the terminal using bash. I have a python script that takes two parameters (paths of input and output) and then the script runs and saves the output in a text file.

All the input directories have a pattern that starts from "g-" whereas the output directory remains static.
So, I want to write a script that could run on its own so that I don't have to manually run it on hundreds of directories.

```
$ python3 program.py ../g-changing-directory/    ~/static-directory/ > ~/static-directory/final/results.txt
```

Comment: Check any answers tagged with `[gnu-parallel]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
find .. -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "g-*" | xargs -n1 -P1 -I{} python3 program.py {} ~/static-directory/ >> ~/static-directory/final/results.txt
```

`find ..` will look in the parent directory `-maxdepth 1` will look only on the top level and not take any subdirectories `-type d` only takes directories `-name "g-*"` takes objects starting with `g-` (use `-iname "g-*"` if you want objects starting with `g-` or `G-`).
We pipe it to `xargs` which will apply the input from `stdin` to the command specified. `-n1` tells it to start a process per input word, `-P1` tells it to only run one process at a time, `-I{}` tells it to replace `{}` with the input in the command.
Then we specify the command to run for the input, where `{}` is replaced by `xargs`.: `python3 program.py {} ~/static-directory/ >> ~/static-directory/final/results.txt` have a look at the `>>` this will append to a file if it exists, while `>` will overwrite the file, if it exists.

With `-P4` you could start four processes in parallel. But you do not want to do that, as you are writing into one file and multi-processing can mess up your output file. If every process would write into its own file, you could do multi-processing safely.

Refer to `man find` and `man xargs` for further details.

There are many other ways to do this, as well. E.g. for loops like this:

```
for F in $(ls .. | grep -oP "g-.*"); do 
  python3 program.py $F ~/static-directory/ >> ~/static-directory/final/results.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, here's what I would write:

```
find .. -type d -name "g-*" -exec python3 program.py {} ~/static-directory/ \; > ~/static-directory/final/results.txt
```

You haven't mentioned if you want nested directories to be included, if the answer is no then you have to add the `-maxdepth` parameter as in @toydarian's answer.